# Generating JLabels on demand

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I would like to be able to generate a map, of sorts, which places small JLabels at coordinate locations on a panel. The problem is that I need them to be randomly generated, so I don't know in advance how many I will have. Is there a way to do that?

I hope this isn't breaking any Java coding taboos - I'm self-taught.

*Edit:
I know I was vague - my program is huge and cumbersome and I have developed my own conventions (which I'm sure would raise the hackles of real java coders :-P) I should have specified that I have a class Location, and I can easily generate random locations. The trouble I have is in creating a new jLabel for each of those locations. Here's what I have:

```
//Method called after a new Location has been created, to add it to the map
public void addLocation(Location newLocation)
{
    int xx = newLocation.getXloc(); 
    int yy = newLocation.getYloc();

    for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        JLabel tempLabel = new JLabel(); //tempLabel instantiated elsewhere (is that a problem?)
        tempLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tempLabel.setBounds(xx,yy,3,3);
        Map.add(tempLabel); //Map is a JPanel with null layout manager 
        tempLabel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to do anything. No black dots appear on the map. Maybe now it's as simple as incorrect implementation of adding a label to a panel?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that might help you in some way, your question was a little vague on the details but i think this is what you are looking for.

```
public void generate(JPanel panel)
{
    int panelWidth = 500;
    int panelHeight = 500;
    JLabel label;

    Random random = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillies());
    int numberOfLabels = random.nextInt(100);
    for(int x=0;x<numberOfLabels;x++)
    {
        int locX = random.nextInt(panelWidth);
        int locY = random.nextInt(panelHeight);

        label = new JLabel("Hello World!!");
        label.setLocation(locX,locY);
        label.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

If this is not the answer you are looking for or you need more help, let me know ill be glad to help. Hope this helped!!

Update: This is the way you would do it with a MouseListener:

```
public void generate(JPanel panel)
{
    int panelWidth = 500;
    int panelHeight = 500;
    JLabel label;

    Random random = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillies());
    int numberOfLabels = random.nextInt(100);
    for(int x=0;x<numberOfLabels;x++)
    {
        int locX = random.nextInt(panelWidth);
        int locY = random.nextInt(panelHeight);

        label = new JLabel("Hello World!!");
        label.setName("World Label");
        // If some of your labels have the same Text then you should set a different
        //     name to each one so that you can tell the difference between them
        //     when you handle the mouse events.
        label.addMouseListener(new PlayerListener());
        // PlayerListener would be the class that implements MouseListener
        label.setLocation(locX,locY);
        label.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

This would be your MouseListener:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
    if(label.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("World Label"))
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
    }
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
```

This MouseListener should only be added to JLabels because of the type cast. Hopefully this helped!

Comment: Thanks, that code did at least give me an idea - using the for loop just to create new labels each time, but something's still broken. I've edited my original post with more information.

Comment: Heres your solution, if you want to set custom locations of all your components you need to disable layout manager by calling setLayout(null); in the constructor of your map class that extends JPanel. Then for all of the components you must specify their position in coordinates, then you must specify wither the component is visible or not by calling component.setVisible(true); Hope this helped!

Comment: Well, I'm feeling thoroughly incompetent now. I'm using NetBeans IDE. I've changed the layout manager for Map to null, I think I'm specifying the coordinates correctly, and it's set to Visible. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out, and I feel even more ridiculous. Your solution fixed everything. The labels just weren't showing up. I put in some text, rather than just changing the background, and voila! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it alright if I throw more complication at you? You don't have to follow me down my rabbit hole if you don't want to, but do you happen to know if it's possible to add a mouselistener to each of these jlabels as they're created? Is it possible to create a handling method for each one, or would they point to the same method, if I added this to the end of the addLocation method: 
    tempLabel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
       public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tempLabelMouseEntered(evt);
        }
    }

Comment: I dont mind at all, if you need anymore help ill be glad to help. I added some more code for you that i think will help you a lot. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> but do you happen to know if it's possible to add a mouselistener to each of these jlabels as they're created?

Sure its possible. You don't even need to create a new listener every time. You can create one listener that is used by all labels. Then inside the listener code you use:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)event.getSource();
```

and you have access to the label that generated the MouseEvent.